# Continuous probability for time overlap

Tags: probability, integration

The following is an example from Introduction to Probability by Dimitri P. Bertsekas example 1.5. I am having trouble deriving the answer for the example

X and Y have a meeting at a given time and each will arrive at the meeting place with a delay between 0 and 1 hour, with all pairs of delays being equally likely. The first to arrive will wait for 15 minutes and will leave if the other has not yet arrived.

This is how I approached

The sample space is

$$\Omega = \int_0^{60} x \int_0^{60} y \,dx \,dy$$

The event that $x$ is waiting for $y$

$$P(x) = \int_{0}^{45} x \int_{x}^{x+15} y \,dx \,dy$$

The event that $y$ is waiting for $x$

$$P(y) = \int_{15}^{60} x \int_{x-15}^{x} y \,dx \,dy$$

The probability of meeting is

$$\frac{P(x) + P(y)}{\Omega}$$

I got $\approx 0.44$ as my answer however the answer is 7/16

Is my approach completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The $x$-axis represents the delay of X (in quarter hours, sorry!) and the $y$-axis the delay of Y.

You want the shaded area as a proportion of the area of the whole square. It is easy to calculate the area of the two triangles (which correspond to them not meeting) and so to get 7/16.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to solve this without the graph?

Comment: Of course, a graph just makes it clearer.

Comment: If you compare your integrals with the diagram, you will see that they are not quite right. Suppose, for example X is 55 minutes late and Y is 59 minutes late.